# Why does this horizontal line appear across the model when I add a subsurf modifier?

Tags: subdivision-surface

So I have a screenshot for you, of the rear end of my female 3D model, and there in a strange indent going through it. Which only appears when I use a subdivision surface modifier.

And no, I am not talking about here butt crack xD I am talking about the horizontal line that goes all the way around.

It is unique from the possible duplicate due to the fact that it is a horizontal line, and thus is not a mirroring issue.

Here is the image: 
[image]

Comment: Perhaps there is a gap that was not stitched up perfectly in the mesh. It may be easier for me to identify if you upload your .blend file so that I can directly see what's wrong with it. You can use this link to upload: blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: When you have such errors it usually means that the geometry is not connected, so the subsurf stops at the edges. You might have duplicated unconnected vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Go in edit mode delete the faces (but not the points) where there is the horizontal lines, and then create the faces again.